# Explanation of touchpoint density in touchscreens

Tags: touchscreen, touch-panel

I'm looking at touchscreen supplier specs such as [this one](http://kingtouch.en.made-in-china.com/product/DqOQNaVjferi/China-22-Surface-Capacitive-Touch-Screen-KTT-CA22K-.html).

What does the specification "touchpoint density" expressed as touches/sq.cm sq.in or mean? The value given is "> 100,000 touches/in^2". Does this mean it can differentiate between pinpoint touches at 100,000 points at every square inch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 1 square inch of touchscreen area, there are more than 100,000 distinguishable points.  It doesn't mean it can distinguish between a touch at (0,0) and (1,0), but that the touchscreen controller could return 100,000 different points.

Comment: So, to clarify, since sqrt(100000) is about 316, the controller can return any coordinates from (0,0) to (316,316) in one square inch?

Comment: Be careful in general this resolution is a math exercise.  The sensing methodology gives four signals which are used to calculate the center of touch which is reported.  The number of points reported is more a function of how many "decimals" I include in the calculation.  To borrow an ADC parallel, beware the ENOB of reported position.